# Creating Datavalidation with custom Formula

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create DataValidation for a cell in google sheets with google app scripts, but i cannot find the syntax to create a custum formula for the validation.

My idea is to create a code to validate a time format HH:MM. For this matter i already have a a working Regexp (function CheckRegexp)

The only documentation i´ve found so far to this issue is this one: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-criteria

```
function test() {
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        var cell = sheet.getRange("E4");
        var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CUSTOM_FORMULA
        //Custom formula CheckRegexp
        var dv = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().withCriteria(criteria, args).build();
        cell.setDataValidation(dv);
}

function CheckRegexp(input) {
  return /^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/.test(input);
}
```

I want the result to be a Data Validation for my Regexp in a desire range.

Comment: At first, about your idea.. to check format by data validation. It sounds wrong, because we should validate **data** by means of data validation. And we should check (make) format by format settings, including date-time formats. If you still want to input **strings** and check their by regex, we will explain how to do that.

Comment: If i state a format in a column for example HH:MM it will not be validated if a user puts "asd". So the only way i imagine is with a DataValidation or a OnEdit trigger. If you can share another way it would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to set a custom function(javascript-based) as a data validation criteria. Custom formula in this context(`DataValidationCriteria.CUSTOM_FORMULA`) refers to custom crafted formula by nesting inbuilt formulas, which is possible.

#### Possible solution(s):

- Use a edit trigger `onEdit(e)` to check each edit, whether it satifies a condition and clear the cell `e.range.clear()`, if not OR
- Use inbuilt formula like this:

  ```
    =REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(E4),"^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$")
  ```

#### To Read:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)

Answer (score 0):

Just another way for data validation is below:

```
=AND(ISDATE(E4), TEXT(E4, "hh:mm")=TO_TEXT(E4))
```

REGEXMATCH function is also suitable, but it may appear to be less readable for somebody.
By the way, both cases do not reject incorrect numerical input (I dont know why). They only mark cells as "Invalid: This cell's contents violate its validation rule".

Answer (score 0):

It's too late, but might help someone still looking for it. Here's how you can set Custom Formula validation through script:

```
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("A2");
var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CUSTOM_FORMULA;
var args = ["=ISNUMBER(A2)"];
var val = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().withCriteria(criteria,args);
val.setAllowInvalid(false);
val.setHelpText("Please enter valid number.");
range.setDataValidation(val);
```